# Crystal Report Sum of Average

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new with Crystal Report. I have tried many ways but I have not able to solve this issue for a few days. Can someone help to solve my issue?

Here is my results displayed in the detail section after join table A with table B

```
Id   | Charge | Type

D428 | 35     | L

D440 | 54     | L

D440 | 54     | L

D435 | 28     | W

D435 | 28     | W

D448 | 32     | L

D452 | 37     | L

D465 | 20     | W
D465 | 20     | W
```

How do I calculate sum of average for "Charge" based on condition "Type" and group by "Id"?

For example:

```
Sum Avg Type L : 35(D428) + 54(D440) + 32(D448) + 37(D452) = 158

Sum Avg Type W : 28(D435) + 20(D465) = 48

Avg for L: 258 / 4 id = 39.5

Avg for W: 48 / 2 = 24
```

I tried to run total field to calculate for the avg but cannot combine condition and group by in the evaluation section. Can choose either formula: type = 'L' or group by Id.

Comment: I can see there is duplication of records... is it according to the requirement?

Comment: how do you want the display to be? any example records?

Comment: Thanks. These duplicate records due to the join table A with table B. But the requirement to count the charge once for each Id even if it is duplicated.

Comment: The display is to get the average charge for each type: L and W, do not care about Id. Example: Avg charge for L is 39.5 and avg charge for W is 24

Answer (score 0):

1. To get rid of duplicate records use option `Select distinct records` in Database menu.
2. Group by `Type` and place `ID` and `Charge` in `Detail` section
3. Now take `Sum` of `Charge` and `count` of `ID` in group footer.
4. Create a formula `@Average` and write belwo code there: Place the formula to the right most part after the summary and count

   ```
   Sum ({Charge}, {Type})/count({Charge}, {Type})
   ```

Above is just an example when you take summary and count then change the values as per the report.

1. In `L` group you have average for L and in `W` group you have average for W

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I tried your solution but seems it not as what I want. However, I create 2 group Id a Type. Hence I run total field to get avg for charge, evaluate on change of group ID and reset on change of group Type. Hence it can show average for each ID. I also count how many Id for each type. Hence the next step is to sum of the average for each type and divide count of each type. I

Comment: I create for running total field to calculate avg for each type in order to use formula: type='L' . But it is not possible. Your formula yield average for each Id not for each type. The report requires to display average for each type. In this case L=39.5 and W=24. Thanks very much